# Prevent header menu to re render when navigating through page - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to ask if its possible not to re render the header component when navigating through page, because when I do console.log() in the header component it always fire up when navigating through page. Here's is my code:

// Route.jsx

```
<Route component={HeroesPage}>
    <Route path="/reactjs" component={HeroesComponent}></Route>
    <Route path="/reactjs2" component={HeroesCreateComponent}></Route>
</Route>
```

// HeroesPage.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

import Header from "components/common/Header.jsx";
class HeroesPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HeroesPage;
```

// Header.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class Header extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('header loaded');
        // If I will add an api call here, it will fetch to the server everytime I navigate to the page
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><Link to="/reactjs">Reactjs 1</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/reactjs2">Reactjs 2</Link></li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}


export default Header;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try refactoring routes like

```
<Route path="/" component={HeroesPage}>
    <Route path="reactjs" component={HeroesComponent} />
    <Route path="reactjs2" component={HeroesCreateComponent} />
</Route>
```

Comment: You're the man!. This is what I'm looking for. So just a quick question. So i will need to the path="/" on all the pages that I have for example, SkillsPage,ProfilePage so their correspoding header will not render again?

Comment: Actually we need to maintain proper hierarchy of our components to avoid re-rendering. In your case header is the component which plays with router. So `/` holds the Main Component with `Header` and rest all your `children` components that renders inside `HeroesPage`

Comment: So you mean there should be a component that will hold the `HeroesPage` and that component will have the `/` and `header` and also the component children?

Comment: Not like that Every Application needs a root component to hold the entire application tree. Here we're placing that root component to route `/` and rest to their respective routes.